# Ubuntu 22.04 No sound, "Dummy output"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04

since the update I have no audio. No sounds on the computer or on Bluetooth speakers. The only output for audio I can choose is "Dummy Output".

On my keyboard the sound volume buttons no longer work, and I have no toggle for sound volume anywhere to be seen.

My laptop is an i5 Fujitsu laptop.

Edit: The first fix here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html worked to the extent that my output devices and buttons to control the volume showed up. However, I still have no audio, not on the computer or on Bluetooth speakers.

Edit2: my soundcard is Haswell-ULT HD audio controller, Intel Corporation

Comment: Did you try `gnome-control-center`, « sound » tab? Is this where you tried when you wrote "The only output for audio I can choose"?

Comment: Yes, in the sound tab and the Pulseaudio settings I could only select "Dummy audio". I was able to fix that, and now I can select my output audio, but I still have no audio on the computer or on Bluetooth speakers.